How to configure DHCP on CISCO IOS XE with options (60) conditions?
Cisco IOS XE Fuji 16.9:
How can I make the client receive the "bootfile" option, depending on what is specified in "option 60"?
This is necessary in order to transfer the necessary download file to clients with BIOS or UEFI
I tried to use the ip dhcp class, but it only allows you to set the range in the pool

Use a real DHCP server. The ones built into the network devices are rudimentary.

Have you tried bootfile in the dhcp pool configuration for that class? (but to second Ron, if you want to do anything serious with DHCP, don't use the junk built into IOS)

You should just be able to add the following command under the DHCP server config

option code [instance number] {ascii string | hex string | ip-address}

